# How to find specified fields in mongodb in sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

In mysql, I can retrieve specified columns by using:

```
User.find({select:['email']}).....
```

Now I am moving to mongodb, I tried:

```
User.find({select:['email']}).....
User.find({},{email:1}).....
User.find({},{fields: {email:1}})....
```

But none of them works. How could I do this in mongodb ?

BTW: I could do this by using official mongodb driver like bellowed, it's quite simple and perfectly match with the API document, so I am rethinking should I use the official driver(*I don't want to waste time in asking & solving problem like this*), But I don't want to lose the capacity and flexibility of waterline as well.
Any suggestion or advice is mush appreciated.

```
db.collection('user').find({},{email:1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.user.find({},{"_id":0,"email":1})
```

This is working for me in MongoDB 3.x